# Run 'composer update' after a git push

Tags: windows, git, composer-php

I've got a system setup so that people can clone a repo on the server, work on it, and when finished push it back to the server. This repo then does a `git checkout` to the actual 'webfolder'.
But since the framework used it Laravel, and it could be that someone made changes to the composer.json file, I would like to run `composer update` right after the push (on the 'webfolder')
System is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is this possible? I've tried to put something alone the lines of this in de post-receive hook, but that didn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website git checkout -f
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website composer update
```

**EDIT:**

First I got no output at all, but now I got output that C:/inetpub/... was a file, so I changed it to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website git checkout -f

cd C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website 
composer update
```

But that also doesn't work, cause now I get bunch of error stuff which is dumped to a file called `sh.exe.stackdump`. And the only useful thing that file tells me is `Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. So I think it has something to do with permissions?

Comment: the hook is the way go. thus: what was the problem with that?

Comment: Try putting quotes around your file names. And put git checkout on it's own line.